# Edit an optimized Google Maps route

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**Desired functionality**

After gathering pre-defined Start, End and intermediate Waypoints from a database, query the Google Maps API V3 to:

a) Optimize a route based on the Waypoints given.

b) Display such route on a Map. Display the optimal waypoint order.

c) Give the user the possibility to edit the order of waypoints. *Please note: It is not desired to drag the waypoint´s marker to change it´s address. The desired behaviour is to have a list of waypoints as ordered by the API and then to be able to manually edit the order and update the map accordingly.*

d) Save back to the database the final order after the API´s answer and the user´s possible edits.

**What is currently working**

Functionality described in points A and B is covered by the following code:

```
   function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8, <!-- We can also support customizable zoom levels according to the size of delivery area !-->
    center: region
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directionsPanel'));

  google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
    computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
  });

  calcRoute();
}

function calcRoute() {

  var request = {
    origin: 'Chemnitz, Germany', <!-- This will be the main address, we get it from the database. -->
    destination: 'Chemnitz, Germany',
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    waypoints:[{location: 'Mittweida, Germany'}, {location: 'Zwickau, Germany'}, {location: 'Dresden, Germany'}, {location: 'Freiberg, Germany'}], <!-- This will be the list of locations the truck has to visit, we get it from the database. -->
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING <!-- Maps supports many types of transport, but we have to specify this is a particular vehicle. -->
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

    }
  });
}
```

**Question**

Is there any method in the API to support manual editing of the waypoint´s order after the API has optimized and displayed them?

Are there any examples of similar solutions that might help me resolve this issue?

**Additional information**

The reason why I need to support manual editing of the waypoint´s order is that sometimes, there are time constraints for the deliveries these stopovers represent. Therefore, occasionally the user will want to modify the stopovers order to make them more suitably delivered at a convenient time, i.e.: the end of the day, the beginning of the route in the morning, etc.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in implementation for this, but it's not difficult to achieve it.

The order of the optimized waypoints may be retrieved via the `waypoint_order`-property of a route. You may use this order to create a sortable list, when the list will be re-ordered send a new request with the re-ordered waypoints and the `optimizeWaypoints`-option set to `false`

Comment: Awesome, seems like I was complicating myself too much. Thanks!